# Vue Template Compiler Optimizations of JSX/TSX vs SFC

Tags: vue.js, templates, optimization, jsx, vuejs3

Is there a performance/optimization advantage of using Vue 3 SFCs vs JSX/TSX?

A long time ago in Vue official documentation, I read that SFCs are optimized due to their declarative nature whereas JSX/TSX is not due to their imperative style.

Can anybody shed some light on this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote and translate from [Evan You's answer (written in Chinese)](https://www.zhihu.com/question/453332049/answer/1844784032) on [Zhihu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhihu):

> Performance-wise, using templates is way faster than using TSX. With the premise of equal IDE support, using TSX is essentially sacrificing performance for developer preference (doesn't matter if there's no performance bottleneck).

As for:

> I read a long time ago in Vue official documentation that SFCs are optimized due to their declarative nature whereas JSX/TSX is not due to their imperative style.

JSX/TSX and templates are all declarative, the reason why JSX/TSX is hard to optimize is that they are too dynamic to provide sufficient information for the runtime to optimize.